# Javascript code doesn't execute after the page changes

Tags: javascript, xss, onload

So, I'm trying to run this code

```
document.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
document.onload = function(){document.getElementById("title").value="My question";};
```

but it turns out that my function doesn't run the function. You can observe this by doing

```
document.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
document.onload = function(){document.getElementById("title").value="My question";alert('Hi');};
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the function run?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to do. Is this some form of XSS?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I'm trying to create a script that creates a template for a stackoverflow question. Should I add the XSS tag?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yep. Sorry about that.

Comment: You should get a banner on your question where you can accept the duplication...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811582/is-there-a-way-to-have-an-onload-callback-after-changing-window-location-href)!

Here is a quote of the most important part of the accepted and most upvoted answer:

> No, you cannot do it the way you want. Loading a new page closes the current document and starts loading a new document. Any code in your current document will no longer be active when the new page starts to load. - *Source: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13811655/3768784) by [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00)*

Comment: Actually my question is probably a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry. I just like to quote the most important part of the answer of the original question just in case it gets deleted sometimes.

Comment: @DavidMichaelHuber That's really a non-argument. Why would a question with 16 upvotes and an accepted answer with 15 upvotes ever get deleted?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen There is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363892/what-should-be-done-if-a-question-has-its-duplicate-deleted?cb=1) question that made me think it is a good idea to do like I did. Do you think it is bad to give a quote that leads into the right direction?

Comment: I think the general consensus is that clear duplicates should be closed as such, and that replicating the answer just adds clutter to the site. The meta question that you're referring to, describes scenarios that are clearly not applicable here. The general guidelines are here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: "*[...] and that replicating the answer just adds clutter to the site."* That's true I have to admit. I actually thought about users finding this (duplicate) question wanting an answer without going through another question. Anyway guidelines are guidelines! So I am going to go with them. Thanks for informing me!